# How to have input in a command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, command, discord.py

I am trying to get an input in a command so its the command + the input in the same line.

So for example: /cmd input

So then some variable would be equal to input and I would be able to access it and maybe manipulate it.

Here is a code snippet for you to better understand what I am trying to sat

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

messages = []
@client.command()
async def candidate(ctx, userinput): #this won't work obviously
    messages.append('userinput')
```

Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to get your bot to send the user's message? Could you edit your question to be a bit clearer so we can help you better?

Comment: I am just trying to have it stored in some variable so I can access it

Answer (score -1):

You want a command of yours to receive an argument (or more) and then use it. It should be something like the following:

```
@client.command()
async def candidate(ctx, arg): # "arg" will have the first argument the user sent when he used the command "candidate"
    response = "The first argument received was: " + arg
    await ctx.send(response)
```

All of this is explained in the documentation:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=argument#parameters